# Storing large images as BLOB inside a SQLite DB using Bash

Tags: database, image, bash, sqlite, blob

I'm creating a little script to import a big directory of images inside a SQLite database,
I'm perfectly aware that SQLite is not the perfect place to store big blobs but this is how i must do it.

Actually, I'm trying using hexdump:

```
sqlite3 name.db "INSERT INTO table (image) values(x'"$(hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x"' ./filename.jpg)"');"
```

But occasionally, on rather big images, it returns an error:

```
sqlite3: Argument list too long
```

How would you work around this problem?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://effbot.org/zone/sqlite-blob.htm

Comment: it says there's a limitation, but it was removed in sqlite 3 which is the one I'm using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the SQL command is given as a parameter to `sqlite3`, the entire output of `hexdump` must be generated *before* the parameter can be actually used.

A pipe does not have size limits:

```
(echo -n "INSERT INTO table (image) values(x'"
 hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x"' ./filename.jpg
 echo "');") | sqlite3 name.db
```

Alternatively, you could write the command(s) into a file, and tell `sqlite3` to `.read` it.

The SQLite shell in version 3.8.6 or later has the [readfile() function](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#fileio) for reading a file directly.

Comment: Wonderful! I was already thinking of using a pipe, I'm going to try your solution right now.

Comment: OK it worked, i had to edit it a bit, this is the version that worked for me: `(echo -n "INSERT INTO table (image) values(x'"$(hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x"' ./filename.jpg)"');") | sqlite3 name.db`

Comment: this worked for me for a long css value that I needed to insert into a database.